# GA wrong order date

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The site is written in python / django / satchmo
The site is connected analyst. At the time when the user pays for the goods at the checkout page after success, we will send the order to the Google Statistics (id, product, count, price something like that).

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': '{{line.cartitem.product.sku}}',
    'name': '{{line.cartitem.product.get_name}}',
    'category': '{{line.cartitem.product.get_category.name|lower}}',
    'variant': '{{line.size|lower}}',
    'price': '{{line.discount_price|normalize_decimal}}',
    'quantity': {{line.quantity|normalize_decimal}},
});
```

Our date is displayed at the moment when the customer ordered, and GA at night later. When this data transfer api is unable to transmit date

How to fix it?

Comment: check the timezone setting in your Google Analytics website.